# Java: skip method, scanner throws NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, file, methods

I need help in coding a method that reads a file with 2 columns in it (separated with 1 whitespace). Each column containing double values. Then calculate the average value of each columns. In the best of worlds my code would be able to handle following situations:

1. Correct values with correct separation in every row (Ex 1.0 and 2.0, separated with one whitespace) and equal amount of rows for each column.
2. Correct values with uneven separation and equal amount of rows for each column (Ex. 1.0   2.0, separated with 3 whitespaces)
3. One column with correct values and the other also with correct values, columns separated with one whitespace, but with one of them with one less/more row, unequal amount of rows.
4. Both columns containing correct values and correct separation but with uneven distributed and unequal rows.

I attach some pictures as examples

[image: For 1.] [image: For2.] [image: For 3.] [image: For 4.]

My current solution is able to handle 1-3 but it fails when it comes to 4. This is how my method looks like, some of the variables on the top of the method is from tests so not all of them are used in this solution:

```
public static double[] getAvgCols (Scanner reader)
{
    double sum1 = 0.0;
    int number1 = 0;
    double sum2 = 0.0;
    int number2 = 0;
    String temp;
    double avgCol[] = new double [2];
    String[] stringArray = new String[2];

    

    while (reader.hasNextLine())
    {
        if (reader.hasNextDouble())
        {
            sum1 += reader.nextDouble();
            number1++;
            
            if (reader.hasNextDouble())
            {
                sum2 += reader.nextDouble();
                number2++;
            }
            else
                reader.skip("\\s+");
            
        }
        else
            reader.skip("\\s+");
    }
    
    avgCol[0] = sum1/number1;
    avgCol[1]= sum2/number2;
    
    return avgCol;
```

After a couple of tests, regarding nr. 4 above (see also the corresponding attached picture), I've found that the skip method skips the empty "hole" in the right column and then reads the first double in column 1 and then adds that to total sum of column 2. This means that the calculations gets twisted and not correct. It also means that the scanner is going to throw an NoSuchElementException in some cases.

I'm thinking about deleting this and start over with another approach that involves splitting the strings from the scanner input to a string array and then converting that to doubles but I really want this to work! Any suggestions on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008905/read-multiline-text-with-values-separated-by-whitespaces.   You can just ignore all white spaces, and sum.  Dont use nextDouble(),

Comment: @JCompetence Thanks for the tip! I've read through the post you referred to in you're comment and it seems that you suggest another approach similar to the one I thought about and mentioned in the description. I guess I just can't use the skip method in the way a want to.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `Scanner` for this. I would read the file, line by line and split each line using method `split` (in class `java.lang.String`) on the space[s] that separate the two columns in each line. If the line only contains the first number, then the array returned by method `split` will contain one element only. If the line only contains the second number, the returned array will have two elements but the first element will be an empty string.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Path path = Paths.get(args[0]);
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            double sum1 = 0.0d;
            int count1 = 0;
            double sum2 = 0.0d;
            int count2 = 0;
            while (line != null) {
                String[] flds = line.split("\\s+");
                int len = flds.length;
                if (len == 2) {
                    if (!flds[0].isEmpty()) {
                        try {
                            double term = Double.parseDouble(flds[0]);
                            sum1 += term;
                            count1++;
                        }
                        catch (NumberFormatException xNumberFormat) {
                            // Ignore.
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        double term = Double.parseDouble(flds[1]);
                        sum2 += term;
                        count2++;
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException xNumberFormat) {
                        // Ignore.
                    }
                }
                else if (len == 1) {
                    try {
                        double term = Double.parseDouble(flds[0]);
                        sum1 += term;
                        count1++;
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException xNumberFormat) {
                        // Ignore.
                    }
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            double avgCol[] = new double[2];
            avgCol[0] = sum1 / count1;
            avgCol[1] = sum2 / count2;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(avgCol));
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```